# Ubuntu 20.04.3 Wi-Fi stopped working after update to Linux 5.13

Tags: 20.04, updates, internet, uninstall, iwlwifi

My laptop runs Ubuntu 20.04.3, and I had to make adjustments to get it to recognize the Wi-Fi adapter. After rebooting my laptop, the Wi-Fi and ethernet stopped being recognized by the computer.

[This post](https://community.frame.work/t/automated-post-install-setup-of-ubuntu-20-04-on-the-framework/9465) suggests it was an automatic update to Linux 5.13 which made the Wi-Fi stop working.

Without internet access, how can I back down from the packages which were auto-installed (Jan 26)?

The details of the installation from history.log: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q84RA.jpg)

Comment: In that first link it also shows how to fix it even after the 5.13 breaks the fix that was applied to the 5.11 kernel.  I wish I could help you more but I don't have any Intel WiFi cards at my disposal to test out the same thing you have.  Hopefully someone else may have experienced the same issue and fixed it.

Comment: Can you open the grub menu to temporarily revert back to the older kernel?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi this worked! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You can also remove the latest kernel (5.13), and continue using the older kernel (it should not cause *that much* of a security risk).

Comment: Same issue on desktop with B450 I AORUS PRO WIFI-CF motherboard.